# Data from serial async tasks not displaying on android onCreateView

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview

So I have a fragment that does the following:

1. Uses one AsyncTask in onCreate to grab a JSON object from a database entry, using a standard HTTP connection. The data is later displayed in a bunch of text fields. (Tested, works fine).
2. Uses another AsyncTask in onStart to grab an image from a different URL, also over HTTP.

For both tasks, the UI is updated with subroutines in onPostExecute; the TextViews and ImageView are initialized in onCreateView.

Issue: The first time this fragment runs, the image is not displayed (the default appears in its place, suggesting that onPostExecute sees an empty photo URL). When I return to the main menu and select this activity again, the desired image is right where it's supposed to be.

I suspect something needs to be "refreshed," but being a relative async noob, I'm not having any luck identifying it. Any suggestions?

EDIT 1: To illustrate what I'm doing with the UI, here's the code for the photo async task:

```
class FetchPhoto extends AsyncTask<ImageView,Void,Bitmap> {

    ImageView imgv = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {

        Bitmap x = null;
        this.imgv = imageViews[0];
        String tempURL = (String)imgv.getTag();    // the image's URL was previously loaded into the ImageView's tag

        // check if URL string is empty 
        if (tempURL.equals("")) return x;

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(tempURL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            out.close();
            byte[] rawOutput = out.toByteArray();
            x = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawOutput, 0, rawOutput.length);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }

        return x;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap photo) {

        String finalURL = (String)imgv.getTag();

        // update the view with the downloaded photo or the default graphic

        if (!finalURL.equals("")) {  // assumes a valid URL was used to retrieve a photo
            imgv.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
        else {
            Bitmap bmDefault = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.default_photo);
            imgv.setImageBitmap(bmDefault);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** When I set a couple of breakpoints, I found that the async photo task (called from onStart()) is being run BEFORE the database task (called from onCreate()) which fetches the URL for the photo. I am baffled at how this can happen.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the UI is updated in onPostExecute and onCreateView. But for both AsyncTasks, it should be in onPostExecute.
The tasks are asynchronous by definition, so the only piece of code where you know that the tasks are over and then update your UI is in onPostExecute.

Can you maybe paste some code to help us better understand what you did?

Comment: Done. The idea is that setupPhoto() is run only if the fields in onCreateView have been defined. The setup function for the DB fields is built the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was being caused by a race condition: task 2 was executing before task 1 (without the needed results from task 1).

I solved this by adding an interface and a listener to the first async task, creating a semaphore/callback mechanism. The second task was called only within the onFirstTaskComplete code.

I based this solution on the example on the following page:

http://kyanogen.com/asynctask-callback-android/